# jQuery Cookie Plugin: cookie being deleted on browser exit

Tags: jquery, cookies

I have a little problem I cannot seem to fix.

I set a cookie on a page that should last a year:

```
$.cookie("audience_uwf", 1, {expires: 365, path: '/'});
```

This works for the entire browser session. However, it disappears when you close the browser.  Any ideas?

I'm using it to select an audience navigational item in an un-ordered list.

```
if($.cookie("audience_uwf") == null) $.cookie("audience_uwf", 1 ,{expires: 365, path: '/'});


$('#audiencenav div.audience_navigation ul li, #audiencenav div.audience_content ul li').removeClass("selected");
$('#audiencenav div.audience_navigation ul > li').not("ul li ul li").eq($.cookie("audience_uwf")).addClass("selected");
$('#audiencenav div.audience_content ul > li').not("ul li ul li").eq($.cookie("audience_uwf")).addClass("selected");
```

I also looked at the cookie information and it sets the expire time to "end of session." For some reason, it seems the expire time is not getting set correctly.

Update: 
It's like this on all computers and all browsers.

Comment: Have you tested it in other browsers? There is an issue open for this plugin on github concerning this in firefox. https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/issues/37

Answer (score 0):

may be its a browser option that you have set that deletes all cookies when the browser session ends. Or do you have some kind of an addon/extension that manages cookies and does something like this.

I would look in this direction than the jquery cookie plugin.

Comment: It's happening on multiple computers, all browsers. I have other cookies that work just fine on other sites. I'll look into this. Still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I'm an idiot after all.

When a navigational element is clicked I record the cookie like so:

```
$.cookie("audience_uwf", index);
```

I didn't realize that you still have to **specify the same expiration** option even though the cookie is defined already...

It's a gotcha.